# Client-side graphQL sorting - Possible to add a button that reverses a graphql query sort from ASC to DESC?

Tags: sorting, button, graphql, filtering, gatsby

I'm working with gatsby.js, which has graphql built in, and am building a site off  a decent sized data set (1600 items with subfields). I have my index page alphabetically sorted, and I'd really like to add in button sorting features for A-Z (existing) to Z-A, and sort by year and difficulty. I've been scratching my head as I've been going through all the tutorials and documentation, and by this point am not even sure if what I want is posssible.

Ideally, there would be three buttons. One for A-Z/Z-A, One for difficulty(High to low/ Low to high) and one for Year(First to last/Last to first).

Is it possible to add client side buttons to swap the query sorting for server side code?

existing query

```
 query {
    allMarkdownRemark(
      limit: 2000
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___title], order: ASC }
    ) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            title
            categories
            askedHistYear1
            askedHistPercent1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've spent some time on this, and the code is 100% there (I need to add links to each md page), but here is what I've done. Sorting the code with normal html sorting does the trick, as long as you don't mind jumping through some state hoops if you did edge mapping like I did. 16 hours well spent before I finally found a solution.

if material-table isn't my final solution, I'll come back and post a new answer. I want this to be as future-proofed as possible.

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { graphql, Link } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import MaterialTable from "material-table"

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props
    const posts = data.allMarkdownRemark.edges
    return (
      <Layout>
        <div style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>
          <MaterialTable
            columns={[
              { title: "Title", field: "title" },
              { title: "Difficulty", field: "difficulty" },
              { title: "Year", field: "year" },
            ]}
            data={posts.map(({ node }) => {
              return {
                key: `${node.fields.slug}`,
                title: `${node.frontmatter.title}`,
                difficulty: `${node.frontmatter.askedHistPercent1}%`,
                year: `${node.frontmatter.askedHistYear1}`,
              }
            })}
            // onRowClick={<Link to={key} />}
            title=" "
            options={{ paging: false }}
          />
        </div>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}
export default App
export const basicQuery = graphql`
  query {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
    allMarkdownRemark(
      filter: { frontmatter: { categories: { eq: "Statistics" } } }
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___title], order: ASC }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            title
            categories
            askedHistPercent1
            askedHistYear1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to add client side buttons to swap the query sorting for server side code?

You have a misconception here: The GraphQL is not really "server side code" because no server is running in the background. The queries are executed at build time. Hence what you're asking for is not possible. You can't change GraphQL queries on the client.

You can do the filtering/sorting on the client side with normal React code as Gatsby is *just* a normal React app (due to the re-hydration in the browser).

Comment: Thanks friend, this really clarified my problem. I'll give the react sorting a go today instead of trying to manipulate the query after the fact.

Comment: if you found a solution please post it here